# what does zip(*res) mean in python in the following code?

Tags: python, function, zip

Here is a piece of code from Allen Downey's Think Bayes book on the github:

```
def ReadData(filename='showcases.2011.csv'):
    """Reads a CSV file of data.
    Args:
      filename: string filename
    Returns: sequence of (price1 price2 bid1 bid2 diff1 diff2) tuples
    """
    fp = open(filename)
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    res = []

    for t in reader:
        _heading = t[0]
        data = t[1:]
        try:
            data = [int(x) for x in data]
            # print heading, data[0], len(data)
            res.append(data)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    fp.close()
    return zip(*res)
```

The entire file can be seen at this URL:[link on Github for this file.](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkBayes/blob/master/code/price.py)

I am trying to figure out what does zip(*res) mean on the last line of code?  Specifically:

1. What does a '*' do when used as a prefix. and next
2. What does the zip function do to (*anything)

I am new to Python, so I may be asking something obvious.  I see the author's note in the function's docstring, that it returns a sequence of (price1 price2 ...), but it is less than clear to me.

UPDATE:  Following up on James Rettie's anwer, here is what I get when I run the code he provided in Python 3.6:

```
In [51]: zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3])
Out[51]: <zip at 0x1118af848>
```

Whereas running the same code in Python 2.7 yields the results that he provided as shown below:

```
In [2]: zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3])
Out[2]: [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Can you explain why?  The difference is Python 2.7 and Python 3.6 is important to me since I have to still support Python 2.7, but I would like to move to 3.6.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to this link.  It does answer my questions above.

Comment: For python 3 use `list(zip(*x))`. The good thing is that this will work in python 2 as well because applying `list` to a list still gives the same list.

Comment: Nice!  That will work for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In python, * is the 'splat' operator. It is used for unpacking a list into arguments. For example: `foo(*[1, 2, 3])` is the same as `foo(1, 2, 3)`.

The `zip()` function takes `n` iterables, and returns `y` tuples, where y is the least of the length of all of the iterables provided. The `y`th tuple will contain the `y`th element of all of the iterables provided.

For example:

```
zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3])
```

Will yield

```
('a', 1) ('b', 2) ('c', 3)
```

For a nested list like `res` in the example you provided, calling `zip(*res)` will do something like this:

```
res = [['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3]]
zip(*res)
# this is the same as calling zip(['a', 'b', 'c'], [1, 2, 3])
('a', 1)
('b', 2)
('c', 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`zip(*res)` transposes a matrix (2-d array/list). The [`*` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) 'unpacks' an iterable or rows of a matrix and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) interleaves and zips the rows column-wise:

```
> x = [('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3)]
> zip(*x)
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
```

Imagine mirroring the matrix on the diagonal.